# Javascript code works with arrow function and not with normal function

Tags: javascript, function

My javascript code works with arrow function but not with normal function

```
//NORMAL FUNCTION (not working)
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function (number) {
        number * factor;
    }
}
const twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));


//ARROW FUNCTION (working)
function multiplier(factor) {
    return number => number * factor;
}
const twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to return result in `return function (number) {` and with arrow function without curly braces result is returned automatically.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a return statement in the inner function

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function (number) {
        return number * factor;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the return before the normal function is not doing anything?

Comment: Nice catch!
After the fix, `multiplier(2)(5)` can be used

Comment: @HamzaMasood it does, it returns the inner function. If you use an arrow function without braces it just returns automatically. You can also write it as a double arrow function `const multiplier = (factor) => (number) => factor * number`, then you don't need the  return statement on the outer function